# Problem in getting the selected value from a form in symfony

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, symfony6

I'm new to symfony and i want to get a selected value from twig template to the controller :

my code is as shown below :

index.html.twig

```php
{{ form_start(formSave) }}
{{ form_widget(formSave.nomRecherche) }}
{{ form_widget(formSave.searchSaved) }}
{{ form_end(formSave) }}
```

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nomRecherche', EntityType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Recherches Sauvegardées',
                'label_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-label mt-4'
                ],
                'class' => RechercheImmeuble::class,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-select',
                ],
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er): QueryBuilder {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nomRecherche',
            ])
            ->add('searchSaved', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Rechercher',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-5 mb-1'
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

```php
#[Route('/', name: 'immeubles')]
    public function index(ImmeubleRepository $immeubleRepository, RechercheImmeubleRepository $rechercheImmeubleRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        /** @var $form symfony\component\form\clickableinterface */
        $form = $this->createForm(SaveSearchType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->get('searchSaved')->isClicked()) {
            dd($form->get('nomRecherche'));
        }


        return $this->render('immeuble/index.html.twig', [
            'immeubles' => $immeubleRepository->findBy(array(), array('ReferenceProprio' => 'desc'), 100, null),
            'recherchesImmeubles' => $rechercheImmeubleRepository->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'desc'), 100, null),
            'formSave' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

I'm able to get the select working, i get the list but when i select one and click the search button i am not getting the value in the controller.

Comment: avez-vous fait un dd sur $form ? et parcouru l'arborescence ?

Comment: @bcag2 oui, je vois bien le contenu de $form mais je n’arrive pas voir les données.